# Set a default value with angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have an field where the id is set via php:

```
<input name="user_id" type="text" value="<?php echo $this->r->user_id; ?>"  ng-model="entry.user_id" >
```

But the value does not appear in the field.

How can I set it from php to angular js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the initial value of the `ng-model` using `ng-init` instead:

```
<input name="user_id" type="text" ng-model="entry.user_id" ng-init="entry.user_id = <?php echo $this->r->user_id; ?>" >
```

I'm not sure about the php syntax, but this will set value for you as long as the controller has an `entry` object available.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="enquiry.companyName" ng-init="enquiry.companyName='<?php echo $_SESSION['COMPANYNAME'] ?>'"  name="companyName">
```

Sigle quote around php block is important.

Answer (score 0):

You  might want to try [ng-value](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angValue) as well.  Might fit your situation better.  I didn't come across it until today:

```
<input name="user_id" type="text" ng-value="<?php echo $this->r->user_id; ?>"  ng-model="entry.user_id" >
```